# Calculate mean using rollapply only if certain percent of data is available

Tags: r, dplyr, mean, zoo, rollapply

I have a column of hourly data and want to use `rollapply` to calculate the 24-hour rolling average for every hour. My data contains `NA`'s and I only want to calculate the rolling average if 75% of the data for one 24-hour period is available, otherwise I wish for the 24-rolling average to be considered `NA`.

```
  df %>%
        mutate(rolling_avg = rollapply(hourly_data, 24, FUN = mean ,align = "right", fill = NA ))
```

How can I modify the above code to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a function to do exactly what you stated:

```
f <- function( v ) {
  if( sum(is.na(v)) > length(v)*0.25 ) return(NA)
  mean(v, na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

Then use it in place of `mean`:

```
df %>% mutate(rolling_avg = rollapply(hourly_data, 24, FUN = f, 
                                     align = "right", fill = NA ))
```